# Android set input type in view. NOT on TextView or any derived class

Tags: android

I is there way to set input type on a View object? Note it is not TextView or any derived class like EditText, Button etc.

Answer (score 0):

> I is there way to set input type on a View object?

No.

Comment: then how text view does that ?

Comment: @VilenMelkumyan: It has the Java code to support text input. `View` does not, and you asked if you can "set input type on a View object". You are welcome to read through the [9509 lines of `TextView` code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java) to see how they implemented it on `TextView` and its descendants.

Comment: that was rhetorical question

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have constraints that require me to extend `View` and not `TextView`, yet I need to show the soft keyboard of differing types based on focus changes to objects that accept text (the objects accepting text are part of a custom, cross-platform framework and are therefore not `EditText` objects, etc.). Obviously, this is fighting the framework, but that's the situation.

In this case, you would have already needed to override `onCreateInputConnection`, which gives you an opportunity to set up the input type. It's kind of a hack, but you can get `onCreateInputConnection` called again by doing the following:

```
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager)context.
                             getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.restartInput(this); // 'this' is the View
```

I would receive a notification from my custom objects that the keyboard needed to be opened with a certain intent, cached that intent, then performed the above couple lines. That would in turn result in a call to `onCreateInputConnection`, which allows you to set the input type to the cached value.